# Adjust a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Here is js of a chrome extension (I couldn't add the whole js because it is too long).
It uploads the body of the website (text) and the head and opens it in a new tab.
Where should I change? and extension can upload the text which I selected. Headers isn't a problem.

```
var API = "https://www.lingq.com/api/v2/";

chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    var articleURL = tabs[0].url,
        articleTitle = tabs[0].title;

    $('.title').text(articleTitle);

    /* Disable internal links */
    $('a').attr('target', '_blank').on('click', function(){
        window.setTimeout(function(){window.close()}, 200);
    });

    /* Identify user */
    $.getJSON(API + 'profiles/', function(data){
        chrome.cookies.get({url: API, name: 'csrftoken'}, function(cookie){
          var profile = data.results[0],
              languages = $('select[name=language]'),
              courses = $('select[name=course]'),
              tags = $('select[name=tags]').select2({
                placeholder: "Add tag",
                tags: true,
                ajax: {
                  url: API + 'lesson-tags/',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  delay: 250,
                  data: function (params) {
                    return {
                      q: params.term,
                      page: params.page,
                      page_size: 10,
                    };
                  },
                  processResults: function (data, params) {
                    var items = [];
                    $.map(data.results, function(item){ items.push({id: item.title, text: item.title}) });

                    return {
                      results: items,
                      pagination: {more: data.next != null}
                    };
                  },
                  cache:
```

Comment: sorry, it's unclear what you're asking. Do you mean "Where should I change the extension so that it uploads the text which I selected, not the whole website body?"?

Comment: I found a chrome extension works as i said but it is not really selecting because the javascript i used asked me to select again

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multiple-selection/cnccnjdknbhcdcenjmelmlkpklbhlieg

Comment: no, you haven't said that. Please read your post and edit it so that it's clear what you expect the code to do and what it actually does. Also add the link to the extension from your comment and the link to the whole code if it's available somewhere